# pypyodbc not throwing expected exception upon retry of connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, exception

I am attempting to insert some rows of data in to a SQL Server database using pypyodbc. The code I have written, catches any pypyodbc.Error and if this occurs, retries the DB operation up to a maximum of 3 times. In my tests I have managed to attempt to insert a duplicate key row of data - the exception is caught and the retry begins. The problem is that upon the retry the exception is not caught and the code hangs. Here is the code:

```
# attempt to connect to the db - if unsuccessful, try up to 3 times
for i in range (3):
    try:
        # connect to db
        db = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=password")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # Loop round assigning the values in the lists at the given index to a new variable
        for j in range (0,sector):
            value1 = list1[j]
            value2 = list2[j]
            value3 = list3[j]

            # print each of the values, as a sanity check
            print('Value 1 = ' + value1)
            print('Value 2 = ' + value2)
            print('Value 3 = ' + value3+ "\n")

            #if (value1 is not None and value2 is not None and value3 is not None):
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?,?,?)''', (value1,value2,value3))
            cursor.commit()

        # close off the open connections
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        # if successful, break out of the loop so there is no retry
        break

    # if there is a mysql exception thrown, print a message and retry
    except pypyodbc.Error, e:
        message = "Connection attempt " + str(i+1) + ": " + str(e)
        print(message)

    # if we reach this stage for a 3rd time, exit the program as no connection is possible and send an error email
    if i == 2:
        message = message + "\nThe script will now terminate."
        print (message)
        send_error_email(message)
        sys.exit()
```

Upon the first attempt the values are written to the console and the exception (u'23000', u"[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert duplicate key row in object....) is reported. The retry kicks in and the values are written to console again. This is where the program hangs. Why is the exception not being caught on the retry?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is repeating the whole insertion process every time it fails, and after failing the first attempt will fail again as the record has already been inserted.

I'd suggest using a counter instead of a for loop to limit your trials:

```
trials = 0
db = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=password")
cursor = db.cursor()

for j in range (0,sector):
    assert trials < 3
    value1 = list1[j]
    value2 = list2[j]
    value3 = list3[j]
    print('Value 1 = {0}\nValue 2 = {1}\nValue 3 = {2}'.format(value1,value2,value3))
    try:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?,?,?)'''
                       , (value1,value2,value3))
        cursor.commit()
    except pypyodbc.Error, e:
        trials += 1
        message = "Connection attempt " + str(trials) + ": " + str(e)
        print(message)
    except AssertionError:
        message = message + "\nThe script will now terminate."
        print (message)
        send_error_email(message)
        sys.exit()

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Hope that helps.